# Prove $G$ of order $n \geq 3$ is nonseparable if $\text{deg}\; u + \text{deg}\; v \geq n$ for every non-adjacent vertices $u,v \in V(G)$.

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove $G$ of order $n \geq 3$ is nonseparable if $\text{deg}\; u +  \text{deg}\; v \geq n$ for every non-adjacent vertices $u,v \in V(G)$.

Here's my attempt:
Suppose the contrary, that all $u-w$ paths cross $v$, (i.e it is a cut vertex). then removing $v$ will create two disjointed vertices sets $|G_1|=n_1,|G_2|=n_2$ s.t $u \in G_1$ and $w \in G_2$, and $\text{deg}\; u-1 +  \text{deg}\; v-1 \geq n$.

from this point i'm not sure how to show a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Ore's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem) One can prove such a graph contains a Hamiltonian cycle.
Since a graph with a Hamiltonian cycle is:

1. Connected
2. Does not contain cut vertex

It is non-separable.

---

Edit: This was a huge overkill.

It is sufficient to prove:

> **Prop**: Every pair of non-adjacent vertices have at least two common neighbors.

Comment: i did it another way, can you please validate my proof ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i finally figured this out:
we would have $1 \leq w \leq n_i-1$, for $w\in G_{\{1,2\}}$ and $n_1 + n_2 = n-1$

Now by the hypothesis: $\text{deg } v + \text{deg } u \geq n \\ \implies n_1-1 + n_2-1 =n_1+n_2-2\geq n \\ n-1 \geq n+2$.

which is clearly a contradiction.

is this proof valid ?

Comment: It is a bit hard to follow where the proof in the question ends, and the proof here begins. I suggest you write a complete proof as an answer, You don't have to prove it as I did, It was redundant.